# Zend select object - building a query

Tags: sql, zend-framework, select, inner-join

How can I write the query below in Zend Select object notation so using ->join()->where() etc?

```
    SELECT t.id, t.user_id, t.added_date, u.id, u.phone, bk.call_status 
FROM `transaction` t
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT id, MAX(added_date) AS addedDate
    FROM `transaction`
    GROUP BY id
    ) gt 
ON t.id = gt.id AND t.added_date = gt.addedDate
LEFT JOIN `user` u ON t.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN `bok_call` bk ON bk.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE NOT  t.user_id = 'null'
AND addedDate BETWEEN '2008-05-04 17:51:48' AND '2009-05-04 17:51:48'
AND NOT u.phone = ''
AND bk.call_status IS null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example this way:

```
$joinSelect = $model->select()
                    ->from('transaction'), array('id', 'addedDate' => 'MAX(added_date)'))
                    ->group('id');

$select = $model->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from(array('t' => 'transaction'), array('id', 'user_id', 'added_date'))
                ->join(array('gt' => $joinSelect), 't.id = gr.id AND t.added_date = gt.addedDate', array());
                ->joinLeft(array('u' => 'user'), 't.user_id = u.id', array('id', 'phone'))
                ->joinLeft(array('bk' => 'bok_call'), 'bk.user_id = t.user_id', array('call_status'))
                ->where('t.user_id != ?', 'null')
                ->where("addedDate BETWEEN '2008-05-04 17:51:48' AND '2009-05-04 17:51:48')
                ->where('u.phone != ?', '')
                ->where('bk.call_status IS NULL');
```

Be aware that you won't be able to differentiate 't.id' and 'u.id' in result.